# css selection pseudo-element animation

Tags: css, css-animations

Why doesn't the `animation` property works on [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) selector in CSS?

### Basic Test Case:

```css
@keyframes frames{ 
  50%{ color:red } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes frames{ 
  50%{ color:red } 
}

::selection        { background:#EEE;         animation:0.4s frames infinite; }
::-moz-selection   { background:#EEE;         animation:0.4s frames infinite; }
::-webkit-selection{ background:#EEE; -webkit-animation:0.4s frames infinite; }
```

```html
<h2>Selected text should be animated:</h2>
CSS3 animations make it possible to animate transitions from one CSS style configuration to another. Animations consist of two components, a style describing the CSS animation and a set of keyframes that indicate the start and end states of the animation's style, as well as possible intermediate waypoints along the way.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote Tab Atkins and he answers:

> In general, most browsers have trouble running animations on
>   pseudo-elements.  We're gradually fixing these issues, but it's slow
>   work, because pseudo-elements are pretty complicated to handle in the
>   browser.
>
> On top of that, the ::selection pseudo-element is the *most*
>   complicated pseudo-element in all of CSS.  It's so complicated, we
>   explicitly undefined it in our specs until we figure out how to
>   actually specify it in a way that works well.

Answer (score 3):

Most of what I see on [animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) is:

> Applies To: all elements, ::before and ::after pseudo-elements

Which suggests not other pseudo-elements or states?

Comment: I'm not a CSS-expert and don't know that this is the reason

Comment: I think they just simply forgot to add it! there is no reason whatsoever not to support it

Comment: I think it was just missed as well. Perhaps ask Tab Atkins?

Comment: Yeah, it is a good idea though - I like what you were doing there

Comment: I had this vision of something so cool..this code is just a simple demonstration of the problem. if this could be done..it opens a world of great creative possibilities. All I can do is sit in my chair and wait for for the C or C++ guy to fix the browser's code I guess.

Comment: @vsync: `::selection` was dropped from the spec so there's no reason it should be mentioned in any other specs or a browser should continue supporting it.

Comment: @BoltClock - do you know the reason it was dropped it from the specs? it's not like it's some crazy selector no one would want or need.

Comment: It's summed up in the reply that you quoted - it's not about people not wanting or needing it but that it's too hard to implement properly.